# Error reading an integer

Tags: java

I am getting an error when I try to read an integer with scanner. I'm using Scanner to read it then add it to a switch.

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        int switchVar = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner("System.in");
        while(switchVar != 5)
        {
            System.out.println("op");
            switchVar = sc.nextInt();
            switch(switchVar)
            {
            case 1 :
            //Data
            case 2 :
            //Data
            }
        }
    sc.close();
    }
}
```

The console error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Line 18 is switchVar = sc.nextInt(); Thank you.

Comment: What do you think `new Scanner("System.in")` does and why?

Answer (score 1):

You are scanning the `String` `"System.in"`, not the system input!

Just remove the double quotes surrounding it.

Also make sure your switch has `break` statements after your `//Data` code if you don't want them to fall through.